# Android unit testing how to test observable and Subscriber

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, android-testing, android-junit

Hi Following is my part of code which I want to test with various requests but I am unable to test as it is observable subscriber patter any idea how to mock subscriber or how to wait for a result in unit testing

```
api.loadData(request)
            .observeOn(schedulers.main())
            .doOnNext(this::addDataCheck)
            .subscribe(
                    data -> onDataLodaded(listener, data),
                    e -> onAdFailedToLoad(listener, Api.error(request), e)
            )
            .addTo(disposables);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the Observable you could use the `test()` method of Observable to get a [`TestObserver`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/observers/TestObserver.html) or use `blocking*()` methods like `blockingSubscribe()`, `blockingFirst()`, etc.

In most cases you won't have access to them or you have already called `subscribe()` on them. Then the answer depends on the JUnit version you are using.
In general you will have to change the Handler for the RxJava and RxAndroid schedulers like this:

```
RxJavaPlugins.setComputationSchedulerHandler(scheduler -> Schedulers.trampoline());
RxJavaPlugins.setIoSchedulerHandler         (scheduler -> Schedulers.trampoline());
RxJavaPlugins.setSingleSchedulerHandler     (scheduler -> Schedulers.trampoline());
RxJavaPlugins.setNewThreadSchedulerHandler  (scheduler -> Schedulers.trampoline());

RxAndroidPlugins.setMainThreadSchedulerHandler(scheduler -> Schedulers.trampoline());
```

With this all your tasks will be run on the test thread of the JUnit test.

### JUnit 4

JUnit 4 uses `Rule`s to change behaviour for all test methods, like changing the Schedulers of RxJava, for this extend `TestRule` and implement the methods as needed. Rules are used like this:

```
public class TestClass {
    @Rule public TestRule testRule = new MyTestRule();

    // your tests
}
```

See the [official wiki](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Rules) or for example [here](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-4-rules) for more information about `Rule`s.

### JUnit 5

JUnit 5 uses `Extension`s instead of `Rule`s to apply modifications to all test methods. You could for example use this class:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.BeforeAllCallback;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext;

import io.reactivex.rxjava3.android.plugins.RxAndroidPlugins;
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.plugins.RxJavaPlugins;
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.schedulers.Schedulers;

public class RxInstantExecutorExtension implements BeforeAllCallback {
    @Override
    public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext context) {
        RxJavaPlugins.setComputationSchedulerHandler(scheduler -> Schedulers.trampoline());
        RxJavaPlugins.setIoSchedulerHandler(scheduler -> Schedulers.computation());
        RxJavaPlugins.setSingleSchedulerHandler(scheduler -> Schedulers.trampoline());
        RxJavaPlugins.setNewThreadSchedulerHandler(scheduler -> Schedulers.trampoline());
        RxAndroidPlugins.setMainThreadSchedulerHandler(scheduler -> Schedulers.trampoline());
    }
}
```

in your test like this:

```
@ExtendWith(RxInstantExecutorExtension.class)
public class TestClass { // your tests }
```

More information about extensions are in the [official user guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions) or for example [here](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-extensions).

Because the question is tagged with "android", here a reminder that a `Rule`/`Extension` for the scheduling of `LiveData` has to be added if it is used.